# java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.proxy4.$Proxy100 cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor (jdk.proxy4.$Proxy100 is

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm, full-text-search

[image]

I have error in line 36 when I test in postman [localhost:8081/post/search?searchKey=1](https://localhost:8081/post/search?searchKey=1). How to fix it to execute hibernate full text search ?

My github code is [Github code](https://github.com/Toan1606/hibernate-full-text-search)

Comment: Please don't post images, add your code and error messages as text in your question.

Comment: @dunni I have already push my code to github. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't matter, add all relevant information to the question itself, so that it can be answered without having to comb through external resources.